# Visual Studio project not saved

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Somebody **please** tell me it is possible to recover Visual Studio source after VS crashes!

I have just spent 5 hours writing a new utility app, and running it with the "Save before Build" option turned on, as well as AutoRecover every 5-mins. But after VS crashed I am unabled to find anything other than an empty project folder!!! I can't believe that files are only "saved" to memory?!? That can't be right! That 5 hours of work has to be **somewhere** on the disk?

I attempted to reproduce the scenario by creating a Junk project, running it, and then killing VS using Task Manager. It wasn't quite the same situation as a dialog box actually popped up asking to save the project. I ignored this and continued the kill. I was then able to find the Junk source in C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects as advised - but not my earlier project.

I think it's gone.

Comment: If it is not there, it was likely cleaned up. Your only real option now is to not touch your machine and run a disk recovery utility to see if you can undelete some of the files and recover some of your work.

Comment: "ALT+F, S" and "CTRL+S" are your friends.  I don't think I go more than 2 minutes without doing one of those.

Comment: Still being bitten by this in 2012, and no, @ChrisLively, Ctrl+S does not do anything, it just saves to the temp directory. Which C# wipes on startup. You have to deliberately save the Solution which is *Ctrl+Shift+S*.

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown: Ctrl+S should save the file you are currently working on (not to temp, but a real save).  However, that may be different depending upon your own configuration.  My point was simply that I've never trusted an "auto save" in *any* tool and instead prefer to perform a regular save quite often.  2+ years after my original comment and I still believe this is true.

Comment: @ChrisLively: Sorry for the confusion, I was using Visual C# Express 2010, which may differ from Visual Studio (frustration caused inattentiveness). In C# Express, if you have not saved the solution, the solution has no folder, and pressing Ctrl+S saves to temp. It is the only situation I have ever come across where Ctrl+S was not enough. I do not trust auto save either.

Comment: This has to be the worst new feature we never asked for! I've lost some three projects this way. (Yes I am sometimes a bit absent minded). I have Visual Studio ultimate. Hitting Ctrl-S will not help you need to explicitly save the *Solution*

Comment: Can't agree more. This feature is SO BAD it can hardly be called a feature. You eaither know about this or you will eventually loose hours (days in my case) of work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to make sure this doesn't happen again in the future, you can go to

**Tools** > **Options** > **Projects and Solutions**

and check the item

**Save new projects when created**

Comment: Note that you may need to check "Show all settings" in VS 2010.

Comment: This setting is not currently available in Tools > Options > Project and Solutions

Comment: @NelsonNyland You're correct, I can't find it in Visual Studio 2022.  That suggests to me that no one liked this "feature" and it's been removed.  From chatter I've seen online, it seems that perhaps the feature was sometimes buggy and the temporary project couldn't even be found in the temporary folder where it ought to be.  If the box is always checked, then in the worst case you have to delete a bunch of temp projects later.  But if the box is unchecked, potentially you're created temporary projects, not realizing, and later they're lost.  That's bad enough to kill the feature.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem as the poster. I ran (and thus implicitly saved) the project several times, but apparently the source is gone.

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Backup Files\<ProjectName>\
```

Only contains an empty folder with the project name

```
C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local
```

Does not even contain a folder named *Temporary Projects*

I searched all of C: and found nothing relevant.

Comment: +1 for saving Days of work, which where destroyed by corrupted Recovery File

Answer (score 4):

Until you actually hit save solution, the project is saved in a temporary directory. This allows you to create quick scratch projects and not clutter up your projects folder. Hopefully it hasn't been cleaned up yet, but if not, it will be in you application data directory. On Vista, that is

```
C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects
```

Sorry, I forget what that was on XP.

Moral of the story, if it's not a scratch project, save the project early.

Comment: Thank you sir, you just saved my day :), found it in `Temporary Projects` like you said (Windows 7)

Answer (score 1):

For Visual 2010 C# ... I made a simple WPF project and it moved to 
C:\Documents and Settings\scharusaengrit\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files
after I rebooted my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I recovered a source file saved in

C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Backup Files\<ProjectName>\

(this was on Vista)

Answer (score 0):

grep/search your entire drive for sln, proj and cpp (or whatever language) files.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want VS Management Studio files, I just found mine in `C:\Users\<<User>>Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files\Solution1\` as `~AutoRecover%` files...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after a power loss on a WIP project which I hadn't saved! You think we'd know better by now!

This awesome bit of software, [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) scanned my disk and I managed to get my files back after filtering *.cs. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you open website from visual studio.

Just save your project to another location..

file > save as > "your location"

that's it

Answer (score -1):

Indeed it does.  Check your two projects folders. Both may contain your project and yet one is a folder with nothing but a .sln file in it.

I'm very confident your work is on your disk somewhere in your Documents folder :).  If all is set to defaults.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently some versions of windows store backups of your files. if non of the above suggestions worked for you, you may try [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/05/21/using-vista-previous-versions-to-restore-files-you-thought-you-d-lost.aspx).